# Math in the title changes to lowercase automatically (and math symbols render error)

Tags: titles, chapters, classicthesis

Say, you need upper case math symbols in a chapter title. 
If one uses `classicthesis`, the pdf shows a right title with, unfortunately, wrong headings in the next page.

[image]

How to fix this unwished case-change? If one uses e.g. `\hat{A}`, one even gets an error. (this next MWE  shows for instance `the ea-genus` in the headings,  and an error).

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{
 pdfspacing,
                     subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}                                        

% \PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}        
    \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace} % to get the spacing after macros right  
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}


\chapter{The $ \hat{A} $-genus } 

 ...is defined somewhere in next pages

 \newpage

 blah blah....


\end{document}
```

How to protect the math-part in the title, so that it is also shown as such in the page's headings?

Comment: the math problem is why the ams gave up on using small caps for titles and running heads, and instead uses all caps with `\uppercasenonmath` to protect against the opposite problem (making all lowercase math uppercase).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A protected command helps:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\hatA}{\ensuremath{\hat{A}}}
\begin{document}
\chapter{The \hatA-genus}
```

And with some bookmark support:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\hatA}{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \ensuremath{\hat{A}}%
  }{%
    \^A%
  }%
}
```

Comment: i suspect the math `A` is going to be taller than all the rest of the running head.